# How do I create the TBody tag in a Table with pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

How is a TBody tag created within a Table tag using pure JavaScript? (No manual tampering with HTML code). There is the `HTMLTableElement.createTHead()` and `HTMLTableElement.createTFoot()` functions, but no functions concerning the TBody element. To add to this, once you've created a THead element, all the following rows added to the table using `HTMLTableElement.insertRow()` are added to the THead element.

How then would you go about creating a TBody element below the THead without manually tampering with the HTML?

Comment: why note just `HTMLTableElement.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'))` ?

Comment: Considering the existence of the two aforementioned create functions I assume there's an equally elegant method of creating a TBody.

Comment: Why? Why do this to yourself? It's much faster and readable to just append a tbody and it's even faster and simpler to just inject it through innerHTML (although that may have some drawbacks)

Comment: I'm doing it this way because innerHTML is read-only in IE

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [DOM Level 1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-html.html)

> **Interface *HTMLTableElement***
>
> The create and delete methods on the table allow authors to construct
> and modify tables. HTML 4.0 specifies
> that only one of each of the CAPTION,
> THEAD, and TFOOT elements may exist in
> a table. Therefore, if one exists, and
> the createTHead() or createTFoot()
> method is called, the method returns
> the existing THead or TFoot element.

So createTHead and createTFoot are convenience methods that don't necessarily do an actual create.

In contrast, table elements can have as many `<tbody>`s as you like so thare's no need for a special method, and `HTMLTableElement.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'))` will do the complete job just fine.

---

Update: At the time this answer was written `createTBody()` had already been added for completeness to the then HTML5 draft standard, but there were no implementations, and it wasn't known if there ever would be. In fact, Webkit implemented in 2012 and Gecko in 2013.

Comment: would this `.appendChild()` be placed after any existing `<thead></thead>` tags?

Comment: @webNoob13 - Yes. it would become the last child of the table element. You could use `.insertBefore()` instead if you wanted to add it before an existing thead, tbody or tfoot child.

Answer (score 6):

> once you've created a THead element, all the following rows added to the table using HTMLTableElement.insertRow() are added to the THead element.

I stumbled across the same behavior and could not find a function called `HTMLTableElement.createTBody()` either (it does not exist).

But I found out that `insertRow()` (or one of the other functions) seems to include table state logic, as it will create `<tbody>` automatically - unless `<thead>` has been created already.

So the solution is (working with Firefox 62.0.2 (64-bit) on Windows 10) to create the table body first and then create the header:

```js
var tbl = document.createElement('table');

// tbody
var tr = tbl.insertRow();
var tc = tr.insertCell();
var tt = document.createTextNode("tbody");
tc.appendChild(tt);


// thead
var th = tbl.createTHead();
var thr = th.insertRow();

if (true) {
  // works
  var thc = document.createElement('th');
  thr.appendChild(thc);
} else {
  // does not work
  var thc = thr.insertCell();
}

var tht = document.createTextNode("thead");
thc.appendChild(tht);

// tfoot
var tf = tbl.createTFoot();
var tfr = tf.insertRow();
var tfc = tfr.insertCell();
var tft = document.createTextNode("tfoot");
tfc.appendChild(tft);


// 
document.getElementById('target').appendChild(tbl);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

table {
  border: 2px solid white;
}

thead {
  background-color: red;
}

tbody {
  background-color: green;
}

tfoot {
  background-color: blue;
}

th {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

tr {
  /*background-color: #eee;*/
}

td {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Docs:

HTML

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

JavaScript

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement

Answer (score 4):

`createTBody()` does not seem to be [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) yet, but it is there at least as of today and works as expected:

```js
let table = document.createElement('table');
console.log('empty table: ', table.outerHTML);
table.createTBody();
console.log('table with tbody: ', table.outerHTML);
```

Expected output:

```
empty table:  <table></table>
table with tbody:  <table><tbody></tbody></table>
```